# Is there any sort of property that tells me if a request is being made?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash

I have about 100 different requests in a large application I'm making and I'd like to show an icon for when the application is making an request. I would like to show this animated icon when a request is made and then hide the animation when the request is received. Is there a property in Flash or AIR that tells me when a request is being made?

PS I know I can do it manually but after doing over a hundred of these with multiple requests allowed at one time I'd like to be able to just access a property and know if a request is going on or not.

PSS There is the network monitor that exists in Flash Builder. I think it adds a SWC into the application when it's added. I'm using URLLoader for all my requests.

Comment: I say centralize all your 100 places to do a request in one single function, so that instead of having 100 places with `var r:URLRequest=...` and further processing you make a function "do a request" with parameters at least URI and callback to where to transfer the response. There, maintain a list of ongoing requests, and when it becomes empty, hide that animation.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, there isn't. I found the `URLLoader` and `URLRequest` classes left a lot to be desired in terms of functionality and ease-of-use, so I created a wrapper to improve it and implemented a way to track if a request is active in there.

So I have a Request class that makes it easy to add parameters to the request (manages the `URLVariables` object internally with an `addParameter(name, value)` method), cancel a request, prepare the request, send it, handle all errors, and tracks if it is active. I do this by having an `isActive` property that I set to true in the send method and set to false after a `COMPLETE` or any of the `ERROR` events fire. I also use that property to make sure I don't resend a request or try to do something that could cause an error if there isn't a request going. I have a public getter for checking that value externally.

I then have a Handler class that is very generic. It creates the Request object, maps a few functions to it, and focuses on setting up that Request object and handling the response in a single spot (parsing it, outputting it to a standardized return object, etc.).

No class should ever call the Request class except the Handler class and my projects generally have 1-2 dozen classes that extend my Handler class, one for each request I have to make. The code I write should only ever interact with the Handler classes, meaning I only interact with code specifically written for the request I need to make, pushing me to centralize my request code and allowing for easy things like app-wide error handling.